# stacktrace is not being logged by Nlog

Tags: c#, logging, stack-trace, nlog

My NLog is configured as follows

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log${shortdate}.txt" archiveAboveSize="500000" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="10" layout="${date:format=s}|${level}|${callsite}|${identity}|${message}|${exception:format=stacktrace}"/>
      <!--<target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />-->
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
      <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />-->
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

But the stacktrace is not being logged when exception occurs. Is there a bug in NLog?

I have created a wrapper around Nlog and I am logging as follows

```
public void Error(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(message, ex);
    }
```

I get the message in the log but not the stacktrace.

Thanks in advance

Comment: TrustyCoder - could you post the code where you are using NLog to output the exception?  Also are you getting any output in NLog?

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your layout:

```
${exception:format=ToString}
```

Comment: @TrustyCoder: That's perplexing. I am also using NLog 2.0, and this works for me. Are you sure you're calling the correct method overload (i.e. the one that takes an Exception as an argument)?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `logger.ErrorException(message, ex);` instead of logger.Error?

Comment: @SerG What's obsolete? `ErrorException`? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @Snixtor Yes. It's documented right in the code with attribute `[Obsolete("Use Error(String, Exception) method instead.")]`

Comment: @Serg Digging into the source code, it's not as simple as that. Download the source for the v3.2.0 release and the `Logger.ErrorException` method is **not** marked obsolete. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/releases/tag/v3.2.0.0. The attribute you've quoted *is* visible in the source code, in the `ILogger` interface https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/ILogger.cs, but that interface is not part of the 3.2.0 release! Take it a step further, and even though `ILogger.ErrorException` is marked obsolete in the master, `Logger.ErrorException` isn't. This is definitely **not** clear cut.